# Прилипание элемента к правому краю (autolayout)

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

У указанного `TextField` задана ширина и отступ от `правого` края `View`, который в свою очередь располагается внутри `ScrollView`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему же он тогда смещается влево за пределы экрана?

Необходимо, чтобы элемент был всегда у правого края.

Comment: Потому что нужно поставить горизонтальный пробел между лейблом "свадебное платье" и текстфилдом.

Comment: Сделал как Вы и сказали - все заработало. Между элементами добавил отступ с более низким приоритетом. Если напишите в качестве ответа - отмечу как правильный. Спасибо.

Comment: не за что. добавил в виде ответа. смотрите на ютубе уроки по автолаяуту, там их много. (есть парочка на русском) https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-jehhhrJM9abVzAbxcoEPQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поставить горизонтальный пробел между лейблом "свадебное платье" и текстфилдом.

Answer (score -1):

Отступ должен быть задан от правого края элемента до правого края View.
Проверьте эти значения в Attributes Inspector констранты.

[image: скриншот]